# Download all images from a single webpage

Tags: php, image, download

I'm experimenting with PHP, and I've just asked myself a question. How can I download all images from a single website? Let's say that I wanted and images from cnn.com or any other website. Is there any easy way I can download all the images using PHP, and save them on my local computer (or FTP server).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Not *very* easy, but not that hard:

Request the page using [Curl](http://ch.php.net/curl), parse the HTML using [DOMXpath](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and look for the `src` attributes of the images. Then download the images via Curl by adding the full http address to the image path/name.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted just all download all images referenced by `img` elements.

1. Request the remote file with something like cURL.
2. Use a DOM parser (such as DOMDocument) to get all `img` element.
3. Iterate over the `img` elements and use cURL (or similar) to download each image (check the `src` attribute).